# How to delete many documents from collection in MongoDB by _id in NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have an array of _ids, like, for example

```
["a12s", "33qq", "121a"]
```

I know, there are two method in MongoDB like **deleteMany**, where I can delete by specific query

```
  var myquery = { address: 'abc' };
  dbo.collection("customers").deleteMany(myquery, function(err, obj) {
    if (err) throw err;
  });
```

and `deleteOne`, where I could delete one specific chosen document.

I would like to delete the documents with the ids from a given array, but can't find anywhere in documentation something about this. Is it possible in MongoDB?

Comment: you can use `$in` like this `db.collection.deleteMany({'_id': {'$in':list_of_ids}})` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18566590/remove-multiple-documents-from-mongo-in-a-single-query

Answer (score 14):

You are looking for the [`$in` operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#op._S_in). It matches values in an array. You can use it in the [`deleteMany` method](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.deleteMany) filter parameter.

```
var ids = ["a12s", "33qq", "121a"];
var myquery = { _id: { $in: ids } };
  dbo.collection("customers").deleteMany(myquery, function(err, obj) {
    if (err) throw err;
  });
```